# Script doesn't work on startup, but does when run manually

Tags: command-line, bash, mount, scripts

I have made a script that loads a VHD file, fixes it with `ntfsfix` so it can be mount rw and then mounts it. This script works absolute wonders when run via the terminal using `sudo`, but when running it via `crontab`, `~/.profile` or via startup applications, it does not work. The script in question is

```sh
#!/bin/sh
rmmod nbd
modprobe nbd max_part=16
qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 '/media/tygo/1.8TB Drive/MEGA.vhdx' 
ntfsfix /dev/nbd0p2
mount -o rw /dev/nbd0p2 /home/tygo/MEGA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually managed to fix it by sleeping a second after loading the VHD with qemu and running it with cronjob with sudo every half minute using the following two lines:

```
* * * * * sudo /etc/megaMount.sh > /var/log/megaMount.log
* * * * * (sleep 30; sudo /etc/megaMount.sh > /var/log/megaMount.log)
```

The edited script is as follows, the first line checks if it's mounted already:

```
if ! grep -qs '/home/tygo/MEGA' /proc/mounts; 
then 
        sleep 1
        rmmod nbd
        modprobe nbd max_part=16
        qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 '/media/tygo/1.8TB Drive/MEGA.vhdx' 
        sleep 1
        ntfsfix /dev/nbd0p2
        mount -o rw /dev/nbd0p2 /home/tygo/MEGA
fi
```

EDIT:
Forgot to mention that the jobs are added using `sudo crontab -e`, not exactly sure why I then also need to run the script using `sudo`, but it doesn't work without it.

Answer (score 1):

To run your script using crontab, make sure you're specifying full paths:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/sbin/rmmod nbd
/usr/sbin/modprobe nbd max_part=16
/usr/bin/qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 '/media/tygo/1.8TB Drive/MEGA.vhdx' 
/usr/bin/ntfsfix /dev/nbd0p2
/usr/bin/mount -o rw /dev/nbd0p2 /home/tygo/MEGA
```

You could find paths using `whereis` command: `whereis mount`.

Then run crontab with `sudo`: `sudo crontab -e` and add full path to your script:

```
@reboot /home/user/scripts/vhdscript.sh
```

Use your own time instead of `@reboot`

To see if it is executed, you could add some additional information to your script. For example, add to the end of your script:

```
echo "VHD file loading have been completed" | logger
```

Then, using terminal, monitor your script execution by your message appearing:

```
journalctl -f | grep VHD
```